# AngularJS + CKEditor, blur event

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, angularjs-directive

So this is my ckeditor directive (written in coffeescript)

```
App.directive 'ckeditor', ->
require: '?ngModel'
link: (scope, elm, attr, ngModel)->
    ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0])
    unless ngModel then return
    ck.on 'pasteState', ->
        scope.$apply ->
            ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData())
    ck.on 'blur', ->
        console.log "blur"
        # call function from ng-blur
    ngModel.$render = (value)-> ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue)
```

And that is how I use it:

```
<textarea
    ckeditor
    ng-model="data[f.name]"
    ng-blur="update(f.name)"
    onblur="console.log('blur');">
</textarea>
```

How can I call function from ng-blur directive on blur event?
I'm using 1.2.0-rc.2 version of angular.js

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution that works for me (no coffeescript):

```
ck.on('blur', function() {
    if(attr.ngBlur) scope.$apply(attr.ngBlur);
    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData())
});
```